# Logical issue with printf and scanf

Tags: c, struct, printf, scanf

I am revising my basic C to prepare for the upcoming quiz, when i was writing a function to simply take a character input and store it into a struct and print it out again. There is no issue with the compiling whatsoever but i kept getting logical issue. How do i fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct player
{
    char letter;
    int age;
    double avg;
};

int main()
{
    struct player P1;
    char name;
    int age;
    double avg;
    printf("Enter age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Enter avg: ");
    scanf("%lf", &avg);
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    P1.letter= name;
    P1.avg = avg;
    P1.age = age;
    printf("\n Age is: %d \n", P1.age); 
    printf("Avg is: %lf", P1.avg);
    printf(" \n Name is: %c \n", P1.letter);
    return 0;
}
```

If i put in '1' for int, output would be "Age is: 0'

Comment: `scanf("%s", &name);` => `scanf("%c", &name);`

Comment: `scanf("%s", &name);` - You should [read the requirementsof the `%s` format specifier.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). You're not providing an appropriate amount of space for reading a name string.

Comment: Good old buffer overrun!  Never ever write into a C string with an unknown length.  Never.

Comment: Please check the return value from `scanf`

Comment: use fgets to read from keyboard, sscanf to extract from read string

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get name, age and avg. of the player. so to store name , you should declare an array not a character. and for assigning the name to structure variable use strcpy().(direct assignment not works). OR if you taking only a single character as a name then write scanf like this:

```
scanf("%c", &name);
```

check below code, it will help you,

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct player
{
    char letter[10];
    int age;
    double avg;
};

int main()
{
    struct player P1;
    char name[10];
    int age;
    double avg;
    printf("Enter age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Enter avg: ");
    scanf("%lf", &avg);
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    strcpy(P1.letter,name);
    P1.avg = avg;
    P1.age = age;
    printf("\n Age is: %d \n", P1.age);
    printf("Avg is: %lf", P1.avg);
    printf(" \n Name is: %s \n", P1.letter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't show buffer-overflowing code in answers. The `%s` needs a field width, `%9s` in this case -- and why have such a *tiny* buffer at all?

Comment: have you ran this code..?? its working for me.check explanation , if you want store name of player then you shold require the character array not a single character.

Comment: Enter *christopher-montgomery-joseph* as a name and see what happens. `scanf("%s", ...)` is **always** a buffer overflow. Never ever write that.

Comment: Oh and `name` in your code is already evaluated as a pointer, so `&name` is just wrong.

Comment: So? Increase it to 1 MiB, then enter something longer ... it doesn't matter, **this is broken code**

Comment: You should consider re-reading the preceding comments, and doing what they suggest.  i.e. edit your answer with the suggested changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a character data type for entering a string, "char name" which is leading you to undefined behavior.

Instead of that you declare a character array like this "char name[10]" and then read name. but while assigning you have to take care that you can not assign directly you have to use *strcpy* like this.

strcpy(p1.letter,name) (Here letter is also character array)

Answer (score 0):

*Two quick suggestions:*

1)  Unless you are certain the `name` buffer will be populated only by short names, (9 or less characters), pick a more reasonable size for the buffer, such as:

```
char name[100];
```

This will also require lengthening the member `letter` in your struct.

2)  when using `scanf()` to read in variables, the *address of* the variable being read is passed as the 2nd argument.  For variables such as `int a;` or `float b;` you must use the *address of* operator: `&` as a prefix to the variable.  But because the *variable name* of a C string points to the first character in the array, it *already is* the *address of* that variable.  So you do not need the explicit `&` operator when reading a C string into the `scanf()` function.  The return value of the function should also be used to determine if the call was successful.  Change the following line as shown:

```
scanf("%s", &name);
int count = scanf("%s",  name);//note: use return value of function
//  remove &            ^
if(count < 0)
{
    //handle error
}
```